# Complex analysis local mapping theorem and min/max

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)=ze^{iz^{2}}$

the question is to determine the set of points $a$ in $\Bbb{C}$ st $f$ is not one to one 
and to determine

$\min \{ |f(z)|: 1\leq |z|\leq3 \}$

for part 1) I know if $f'(a)=0$ then $f$ is (edit) NOT one to one near $a$, which if I differentiated correctly gives me that $f(z)$ is not one to one near

$z_{1}=\sqrt{i/2}$ and $z_{2}=-\sqrt{i/2}$

my book does not cover this type of question so now I'm not sure what it means by "near"

is my answer just the set containing $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$?

For the second part, it is worth 9 marks but is the answer just 1? I put it into Wolfram and it returned the answer 1 but that looks too simple for 9 marks.

Any help with this part will be most appreciated.

Comment: Solve the equation $f'(z)=0.$ It gives you the points where $f$ in ont one to one.

Comment: sorry,mistype.  it should have said f'(a) =0 then not one to one

Comment: ok,for the second part I think I get it now. I input the wrong thing into wolfram!! I need to look at min on the boundary of the region so the min for |z|=1 and |z|=3 then the min for whole region is the min of these 2 values. Does that sound correct? I get for |z|<3 min values as 3e^2 if anyone can verify?

Comment: on second thoughts im confused again. if I want the min of |f(z)| on |z|<=3 then the min/max principle says I just look for |z|=3 and the min is attained for some point on the boundary, how does this work for my question? do I just look at |z|=3  as this tells me the min for |z|<=3 so anything inside 1<=|z|<=3 is less than the minimum I found on |z|=3?? or am im reading this wrong